# get value from dynamic textbox WP 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I already created the textboxs, and add x:names for it, but I cant get the values

Code where creat textboxs :

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
var CountStackpanelNames = stackpanelNames.Children.Count + 1;
tb.Width = 360;
tb.Height = 40;
tb.FontSize = 25;
tb.Name = "TxtN" + CountStackpanelNames;
tb.Text = tb.Name;

var CountStackpanelNames = stackpanelNames.Children.Count + 1;
```

This count the textboxs

TextBox 1 -> X:name -> TxtN1

TextBox 2 -> X:name -> TxtN2

TextBox 2 -> X:name -> TxtN3...

[image]

How can I recover the value of the textbox by x: names?

Comment: You could use a `foreach` or use another property of the textboxes, like `TabOrder` for example.

Comment: But, how i do to recover the textbox ?  All of the textbos inside of mine stackpanelNames

Comment: I tried some like this :   string[] children = {Convert.ToString(stackpanelNames.Children)};
         
            foreach(char value in Convert.ToString(children)){
                TxtBlockResult.Text = Convert.ToString(value);
            }  But in TxtBlockresult return just a " ] "